# jQuery.html(...) call causes unwanted page scroll

Tags: jquery, html

Calling `$container.html(...);` on a page element causes the entire page to scroll to the bottom. The html we insert does not exceed `$container` size. How to fix it and why it's happening?

The 'tipping point' we found is existence of `id` attributes in the html we are inserting, once those are replaced with `_id` scroll happens no more. Nothing calls the elements after they've been created (which would be an obvious reason).

The layout is rather complex still working on a small repro html. The issue is reproducible across all major browsers.

Comment: Could you reproduce this in a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: working on it - was hoping for it to be a known issue...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and while I was searching for the solution found your question here, but in my case .html() wasn't the problem, it was Visual Studio's "Browser Link" Option which was enabled and causing this, I disabled it under "Start Debugging" Dropdown menu in toolbar and its fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have also just resolved this problem.

My problem was that I had a button inside of a form which was not a submit.

For example:

```
<form><button type="button" onclick="example(this,event)"></button></form>
```

To fix the problem with the above example, I had to prevent default and stop propagation. So my onclick function had something like:

```
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
```

This stopped the unwanted page scrolling.

Just wanted to share in case anyone else comes across this question.